# После установки не дает установить ни единого драйвера - пишет об отсутствии админправ

Tags: windows-7

Перестало устанавливать приложения - писало что нету админправ.
Переустановил, пытаюсь установить драйвера - опять рисует недостаточно прав.
Куда копать? В чем может быть подвох?

П.С. Файлы/папки создаются без проблем в люых местах, в т.ч. и в системных директориях

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько поможет, я бы хотел в комментах ссылку оставить, но не знаю как((
https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2014/05/19/razreshaem-ustanovku-drajverov-obychnym-polzovatelyam-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Помогло передергивание UAC - отключение, перезагрузка, включение, перезагрузка